# Не подгружается картинка через background-image

Tags: css, reactjs

Обратите внимание на div с картинкой, не могу через стили вставить картинку. Проблема именно с div'ом почему-то. Пытался засунуть с помощью - все получилось, путь верный. А когда точно так же делаю с div'ом, то все накрывается. Почему же?

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}>Cars-Catalog</h1>
      <div className="">
        <div className={styles.item}>
          <div
            className={styles.image}
            style={{ backgroundImage: "url(/images-1.jpg)" }}
          ></div>
          <h2>Car 1</h2>
          <p>100 000$</p>
          <button className={styles.button}>Read More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: А размеры у div указаны?

Comment: Бинго! Совсем забыл про это...